# Header file not found for embedded framework inside library for React Native app

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

I'm currently working on a contract job where I've been asked to help integrate a 3rd party SDK with an existing React Native app. The SDK only comes in Android and iOS specific flavors, meaning that it has to be added on the platform-specific side of things (in my case, the iOS side with Xcode).

For the app, the client has created a react native module which gets built into a Library in Xcode, represented by a separate nested Xcode project in `Libraries/MyLibrary.xcodeproj` from the root of the base Xcode workspace project. This library has several method stubs defined in React Native which will need to be implemented in Swift (and likewise in Android), as this is in these methods that the 3rd party platform-specific SDK is utilized.

The issue I'm having has to do with accessing the 3rd party SDK framework in the library's existing bridging header file. I have followed every tutorial under the sun for how to integrate external frameworks with an existing Xcode project. This includes steps about adding the framework to the project, adding it under the `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` sections of the project target, adding it under the `Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries` section of both the project target and the library target, and adding the framework path under `Project Settings/Framework Search Paths`. From here, I add the appropriate import statement to my library's Library-Bridging-Header.h file with `#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>` so I can then access the framework in Swift. (This import statement is copied directly from the bridging header file of the sample project included with the SDK, so I know it is correct and should not be given in a different format such as quotes instead of angle brackets).

Regardless of following all of these steps multiple times over and in various combinations, I still get this error at build time: `MyFramework/MyFramework.h file not found`.

To clarify, `MyFramework` is just an alias for the actual 3rd party framework I'm attempting to integrate, and `MyLibrary` is an alias for the existing library with nothing but method stubs given to me by the client to implement in Swift.

Again, I have read every tutorial and forum under the sun, but none seem to address this very specific issue of integrating a 3rd party framework in a xcodeproj Library within the iOS version of a react native app. I would appreciate any new insights or suggestions anyone might have to offer! And please, please don't just post a link to or copy the steps from existing forum posts about a similar-sounding issue, as I've probably already read it . Understand that I think that there is something subtly unique about my specific circumstances which are causing these same steps from the 10+ articles that come up on the first page of Google and StackOverflow NOT to work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I'll post my solution here in case anybody out there ever runs into the same issue as me.

TLDR - You must add the 3rd party framework in the root of the xcodeproj Library (NOT the top level project) AND ensure that the files were actually copied into that directory, not just referenced from the directory you copied the framework from (be sure to double-check in Finder, since checking the 'Copy if needed' box doesn't always work for some reason). Then, you must add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to your xcodeproj Library's `Build Settings/Framework Search Paths`, and also drag and drop the framework from the root of your xcodeproj Library into the Library's `Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries` panel.

I'll address some of the issues with other tutorials/forums that I found, with hopes that it might help someone else that finds themselves as frustrated as I was in this position.

1. Most only address adding the framework to the base level project, not the obscure case of a project within a project. Therefore, when you start following the steps, it can be confusing to know whether you should be changing the settings of the top-level project or the sub-project. Again, as I discovered, all changes should ONLY be made to the sub-project.
2. There are a few tutorials that do seem to address this situation regarding a project within a project, but the steps describe adding the framework to the top-level project under `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, but I believe the situation described in these tutorials are somehow subtly different than this situation here. Again, only mess with the sub-project.
3. There's a lot of discussion out there about "umbrella frameworks", but that doesn't really apply to this situation, and again, the terminology similarities can make it seem like it's a similar issue. As I understand it, "umbrella frameworks" are discouraged by Apple, but again, this situation is not the same.

Sorry for the long-winded explanation, but I'm hoping to provide the kind of detail I would have liked to have found when I was searching for solutions for this weirdly obscure problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am facing this issue, I have added Swift framework in React Native library and followed steps. However when I try to import swift file in library and calling its showing error